# HQL left join with foreign key from the second table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join, hql

I have two tables A and B. B has a foreign key pointing to A.id (let's say it is called foreignId). I am trying to write HQL equivalent of:

```
    SELECT A.id
    FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b ON a.id = b.foreignId
    WHERE 1=1
```

If I had a key in table A pointing table B, writing to HQL is not an issue and unfortunately all examples I see online are provided with this case. I cannot write a query that select B.foreignId, because one of the main use cases is that B might be null. I need HQL equivalent of the provided SQL.

### Update

Unfortunately, my question is marked as a duplicate with the following [Hibernate HQL Query with outer join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685489/hibernate-hql-query-with-outer-join). As I explained, having a pointer from A to B and B to A is completely different situation. Given link is providing solution my question only if A had pointer to B. It is also answering to these SQL/HQL queries:
SQL:

```
SELECT b.foreignId
    FROM B b LEFT JOIN A a ON a.id = b.foreignId
    WHERE 1=1
```

HQL:

```
select b.foreignId from B b
    left join b.foreignId a
```

Comment: please remove duplicate mark

Comment: It's OK in a question to express the opinion that your question is different to a suggested duplicate, but only if you can explain how they are different. "It is different to that question" or "it is different to all other questions here" is not sufficient to get it reopened.

Comment: I wonder if your explanation of why this is not a duplicate was rather brief, could you perhaps expand on it? I don't use Hibernate, but my experience of gold-badge holders is that when they spot a duplicate, the other question really does provide the necessary answer, even if it is not initially obvious to the question author.

Comment: Please give a [mre]. One does not need to know constraints (including PKs & FKs) to query. When there are constraints, there are just more queries that return the desired result than otherwise. So the duplicate works in all cases. So you may not need to do what you think you need to do. Make sure you understand left join: it returns inner join rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. PS It's not clear why you are giving queries in you update. PS Please don't insert UPDATEs/EDITs, just edit your question to be the best presentation possible.