# HQL left join with foreign key from second table

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I have two tables A and B and I need to select a property from A only. B has a foreign key pointing to A.id(lets say it is called foreignId). I am trying to write HQL equivalent of:

```
SELECT A.id
FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b ON a.id = b.foreignId
WHERE ...
```

If I had a foreign key in table A pointing table B, writing to HQL is not an issue:

```
select A.id 
from A a left join a.foreignId b
where ...
```

Unfortunately, all HQL examples I see online/in stackoverflow are providing an answer to the second case. I need HQL equivalent of the first case.

Note that this question is completely different than asking how can I write simple join queries in HQL, so please be mindful before marking this question as a duplicate. My first question was marked as duplicate with the following question [Hibernate HQL Query with outer join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685489/hibernate-hql-query-with-outer-join) which also exactly the same as my second example.

Comment: Your sql looks strange. What is the purpose of using the following condition `WHERE 1=1`? And why you what to use `LEFT JOIN B b ON a.id = b.foreignId`? Your sql completely equivalent to `select A.id from A`

Comment: Oh, I didn't provide details for WHERE clause, I just skipped the details. I am checking values from both A and B.